# Свойство объекта с таким же названием, как у переменной

Tags: javascript

Безопасно ли создавать такой объект, как `var point = {'x': 100, 'y': 200}`, если уже имеются переменные `var x, y`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Да, безопасно.

Поля объектов не являются переменными, объект не образует области видимости.